# Данный код выдает ошибку AttributeError, я только изучаю Python и не могу понять проблему, почему в конце списка не добавляет значение i

Tags: python

```
class Cars:
    model = ""
    number = ""
    DOC = ""

    def __init__(self, model, num, doc):
        self.model = model
        self.number = num
        self.DOC = doc

    def pAll(self):
        print('Марка авто: ', self.model, '\nНомер авто: ', self.number, '\nГод производства: ', self.DOC)

CarsAll = []

Usin = input("'да', если хотите заполнить анкету \n'нет', если прекратить опрос\n")
if Usin == "да":
    i = input("Введите название марки авто: ")
    CarsAll.append = i
    x = input("Введите ГОС номер авто: ")
    y = input("Введите год выпуска авто: ")
    z = CarsAll[-1]
    z = Cars(z, x, y)
else:
    print('Ну vse тогда')
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: начни с чтения ошибки, поймешь в каком месте она возникает. Загугли ошибку, узнаешь, что она означает. i не добавляет, потому что неправильно используешь функцию append

Comment: Эникейщик, спасибо за ответ,   (i) надо было, не обратил внимания

Comment: @Эникейщик, ответы - в ответы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CarsAll.append = i
Тут ошибка
Ты должен
CarsAll.append(i)

Если это не сработает попробуй вот так
i.append(CarsAll)

Если  оба варианта не сработает то
Попробуй в Faq в Сайте Python.org найти свою проблему

Comment: Гадание какое-то...